# Songs in episode 286 of Fairy Tail when the guild members saw the young boy before the soldiers hurt him

Tags: music, fairy-tail

What's the name of the music in the background in episode 286 of *Fairy Tail*, "Law of Space" that starts around 14:35 when the guild members leap to the aid of the young boy before the soldiers hurt him?

Answer (score 0):

Hope Road is what I've recently figured out through various youtube comments. I searched that title and it came right up!